# Why does the caliburn.Micro explanation not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am working from the [caliburn.micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/) website and they have this example. Why is password returning null?! See here the picture of the example I am trying to work with. 
[image]

My view.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="Username" />
    <PasswordBox x:Name="Password" />
    <Button x:Name="Login" Content="Log in" />
</StackPanel>
```

And in viewModel.cs:

```
public void Login(string username, string password){
    MessageBox.show(password + " " + username)
}
```

I have managed to get the login button to fire the Login method and it shows the username but blank for the password.

Comment: Show the rest of the model. Do you have both a Username and Password **Property** on the ViewModel?

Comment: Try explicitely using the `cal:Message.Attach` e.g. like [here](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions). Just to narrow that down. I'm not sure why that doesn't work (as far as I remember, guard signature should be an action, return `void`, not sure why they're returning `string`). And yes, post something small but repeatable.

Comment: @Nkosi I don't have them as a "property" that is all I have in the model. it returns the username but the password is blank.  is a property like Property{get set}?

Comment: @Daniel just to trouble shoot if you convert the `PasswordBox` to a `TextBox` and try it again does it work? If it does then it mean that the framework does not have a convention registered to deal with `PasswordBox` Control and was unable to bind to it properly.

Comment: Yes that does work. Dam this is driving me nuts. Can't believe no one else is having this problem!

Comment: @Daniel I just checked the [repo on Github](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/487) and someone opened an issue about an hour ago about it.

Comment: @Daniel in the [source code](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/6f76b457a7ce8f9e55efbedd7c291bab1bab89c4/src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/ConventionManager.cs#L253) I also notice that there is a convention for `PasswordBox` You could consider using properties instead so that it binds correctly.

Comment: I'm not to sure how to do that. I see u can in the <PasswordBox password="this is the password"/> and that sets the password  but I haven't a clue how to pull that out to use in the Login method.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using an alternative format which properties instead of parameters in the ViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel : PropertyChangedBase {

    string username;
    public string Username {
        get { return username; }
        set { 
            username = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Username);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanLogin);
        }
    }

    string password;
    public string Password {
        get { return password; }
        set { 
            password = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Password);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanLogin);
        }
    }

    public bool CanLogin() {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password);
    }

    public void Login() {
        MessageBox.show(Password + " " + Username)
    }
}
```

Comment: `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanLogin);` giving me "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" error. Can you please help

Answer (score 1):

The example works on some of the supported platforms, specifically Silverlight, Windows Phone and UWP.

On WPF however `PasswordBox` doesn't expose a dependency property for the entered password the framework can't bind the method input to the control.

One approach would be to create your own attached property that exposes the entered password from the control.

You can then customize the `PasswordBox` convention to use your new property.

Now that newer versions of Caliburn.Micro will be dropping support for some of these platforms it may be time to revisit the example on the homepage.